# NLog pass Configuration values(ConnectionString and configDir) to nlog.config in Main method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, nlog

I'm trying to pass connectionString for PostgreSQL and my Log directory to nlog.config file in Main method, how can I achieve this?

I'm currently doing something like [this](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-2#4-update-programcs)
in Startup.cs:

```
NLog.LogManager.Configuration.Variables["connectionString"] = Configuration.GetConnectionString("databaseConnectionString");
NLog.LogManager.Configuration.Variables["configDir"] = Configuration.GetValue<string>("Logging:LogFilePath");
```

Only problem I have is if I try to log something in Main method, after this DB logging is working fine:

```
Error when writing to database. Exception: System.ArgumentException: Host can't be null
```

at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.d__145.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Npgsql.ConnectorPool.d__24.MoveNext()

Answer (score 1):

I found the way to load Configuration in Main method, here is a way if anyone ever needs it:

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")}.json");

        Configuration = builder.Build();
```

And then I use NLog.ConfigurationManager to setup connectionString and Log directory:

```
 NLog.LogManager.Configuration.Variables["connectionString"] = Configuration.GetConnectionString("databaseConnectionString");
 NLog.LogManager.Configuration.Variables["configDir"] = Configuration.GetValue<string>("Logging:LogFilePath");
```

Comment: NLog.Web.AspNetCore ver. 4.8.0 (With NLog.Extensions.Logging ver. 1.4.0) now supports `${configsetting}`: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/ConfigSetting-Layout-Renderer